# How to set the width of a textbox, depending on a specific format string?

Tags: textbox, width, string-formatting, crop, format-string

I have a `TextBox` that uses a specific format string to display its content. The width of the box is set to take exactly the amount of space that is needed to display the text. For this purpose I use the width that the formatted text would have:

```
box.width = new FormattedText(
              String.Format(Format, value),
              CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
              FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
              new Typeface("Arial"),
              8,
              Brushes.Black).Width;
```

When doing this the textbox almost has the right width. But I still need to add an offset of  `12`, otherwise the area of the text would be cropped by some pixels:

[image]

I got the number `12` by try-and-error. So two questions arise:

1. Why do I need this offset, were does the lost width go to (whitespace and border?)?
2. Is there a better approach to get the right offset than to just guess it?

Comment: Yes those and there's some elbow room dependent on font size versus the size of the control. If you are going to do this (I wouldn't) use the font from the control, not a hardcoded one.

Comment: What about question 2, any suggestion on how to get rid of the magic constant?

Comment: To exact? Not really. You'd have to figure out how windows positions the text. But there will be all sorts of other potential cosiderations, windows display settings for instance what dpi it's on. It's a bit of a hiding to nothing this one, set an expectation of exact and all of a sudden 1 pixel out is congressional hearing and a ruling by the supreme court. Personally I wouldn't go near it.

Comment: Ok different idea: Is it possible to get the currently used width of a textbox after the text has changed (and without setting it to a fixed value in advance)? That would also do the job I guess.

Comment: Not seeing what good that would do, and it always has a fixed value. Is textbox the right component? Do you need an edit facility? We have some apps where we simply drawtext when there's no focus, and then raise a TextBox when it's required.